# How to ensure that Entity Framework Core InMemory database is created per test method?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, integration-testing, in-memory-database

Dears,
I am trying to create integration tests that tests my API controller using entity framework core in-memory database provider.
I created **CustomWebApplicationFactory** that configure my services, including my db context according to [official documentation guideline](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/test/integration-tests/samples/2.x/IntegrationTestsSample/tests/RazorPagesProject.Tests/CustomWebApplicationFactory.cs)
and I used this factory as IClassFixture in my xunit test classes but my tests got broken when they run in **parallel** because as i think **they shared the same database instance**.
This is my configuration

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // Create a new service provider.
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            // Add a database context (ApplicationDbContext) using an in-memory 
            // database for testing.
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
                options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
            });

            // Build the service provider.
            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            // Create a scope to obtain a reference to the database
            // context (ApplicationDbContext).
            using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();


                // Ensure the database is created.
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i think they shared the same database instance

You are correct, `IClassFixture` is a shared object instance across multiple tests.

What you can do to reuse the `ConfigureWebHost` is use the test class' constructor instead. 
That way, all your tests will run the configuration but will not share object instances. You might also need to change the `options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");` to use a random in-memory db name (e.g.  `options.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());`.

The official xunit docs might also help : https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context